# PayPal receber atualização de transação

Tags: php, pagamento-online

Estou a integrar a API Express Checkout e há um problema quanto a notificação de atualização referente a alguma transação efetuada. Como o PayPal me enviará a notificação?

Caso uma transação não tenha sido aprovada no momento, e após 24 horas ela é completada, como obtenho essa atualização?

Comment: Segue um exemplo em PHP -  **[Como Processar Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/)**

Comment: Oi, funciona no modo sandbox o recebimento das notificações de acordo com a implementação sugerida pelo site developer.paypal.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para receber informações, tanto no feedback após checkout quanto posteriormente (em casos de análise mais demorada), você precisa implementar um `Controller` que será acessado pelo Paypal, em um momento posterior, em processo `assíncrono`.

Isto é o chamado [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/), o que acontece no passo 2 e 5 do seguinte fluxo:

[image: IPN Flow]

Fonte da imagem: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

Comment: Oi, funciona no modo sandbox o recebimento das notificações de acordo com a implementação sugerida pelo site developer.paypal.com?